# How to Generate Confusion Matrix on HOLD OUT sample in "caret-xgbDART"?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using "xgbDART" method to train my model available in `caret`. The sampling method is "repeatedcv".

Is it possible to generate a confusion matrix of the INTERNAL holdout sample? I thought printing the final model like in "rf" algorithm would generate it but it does not. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a confusion matrix after training in caret on can just call `caret::confusionMatrix` on the generated train `object`. Here is an example on the Sonar data:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(xgboost)
data(Sonar)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                     number = 2,
                     repeats = 2)


grid <- expand.grid(max_depth = 5,
                    nrounds = 500,
                    eta =  .01,
                    colsample_bytree = 0.7,
                    gamma = 0.1,
                    min_child_weight = 1,
                    subsample = .6,
                    rate_drop = c(.1, .3),
                    skip_drop = c(.1, .3))


fit.dart <- train(Class ~ .,
                  data =  Sonar, 
                  method = "xgbDART", 
                  metric = "Accuracy",
                  trControl = ctrl, 
                  tuneGrid = grid)

confusionMatrix(fit.dart)
#output
Cross-Validated (2 fold, repeated 2 times) Confusion Matrix 

(entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)

          Reference
Prediction    M    R
         M 44.5 13.7
         R  8.9 32.9

 Accuracy (average) : 0.774
```

In order to create a customized confusion matrix (for instance with a custom threshold and without averaging across re-samples one could set `classProbs = TRUE` and `savePredictions = TRUE` in `trainControl`:

and now for instance to use a cutoff threshold of 0.3 with pooled hold out data one would do:

```
confusionMatrix(fit.dart$pred$obs,
                factor(ifelse(fit.dart$pred$R > 0.3, "R", "M"), levels = c("M", "R")))
#output
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   M   R
         M 106 116
         R   8 186

               Accuracy : 0.7019          
                 95% CI : (0.6554, 0.7455)
    No Information Rate : 0.726           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.8753          

                  Kappa : 0.4214          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          

            Sensitivity : 0.9298          
            Specificity : 0.6159          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.4775          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.9588          
             Prevalence : 0.2740          
         Detection Rate : 0.2548          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5337          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7729          

       'Positive' Class : M
```

Comment: Hello @missuse, thanks a lot for your suggestion. In "cross-validation", the algorithm internally holds out one fold of training data for internal validation right? I am talking about that. Like in random forest if you print(model$finalModel) you get it. I was trying to generate similar matrix if possible.

Comment: in k-fold cross validation (cv) the train set is split into k parts, and for each part an instance of training is performed without it and evaluated on it. This way all of the training data is used for both training and evaluation with data the model has not seen. In repeated k-fold cv this is repeated several times to reduce bias which is due to specific data splits which can sometimes be optimistic and sometimes pessimistic. If you are looking for a specific output its best to update the question with a reproducible example and your expectations.